# Need to filter only lookup/master-detail kind of fields from the entire fields on an object

Tags: apex, describesobject, schema

I am querying all the fields on the `Lead` object and displaying them as a picklist on a visualforce page.
I do not want the Lookup/Master-detail relationship fields to be displayed, though.
For removing such fields, I have created a separate method in my class to remove such fields. I want to know is there a way of filtering such fields from `Schema.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();`

My code for querying all fields :

```
mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema = Lead.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Lead.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();` line returns a Map with  `Schema.SObjectField` objects as values.

The `SObjectField` object has a `getDescribe()` method returning a `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` object.

The `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` object contains a method `getRelationshipOrder()` which returns `1` if the field is a child of a master-detail relationship, `0` if the field is a parent of a master-detail relationship and `null` if not.

So in your case, the code will be:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema = Lead.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName : mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema.keySet()){
    SObjectField field = mapLeadFieldAPIToSchema.get(fieldName);
    if(field.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder() == 0){
         //the variable fieldName contains the name of a field which is the parent of a master-detail relationship
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another way by which you can check for a field type!
If it is a reference it will be lookup/Master-Detail.
`Schema.DisplayType fielddataType =fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();`
This will do the work.

```java
List<SelectOption> leadList = new List<SelectOption>();
String objType='Lead';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objType);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
    //get all the fields label for Lead Object
    String fieldLabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();

    //get data types for each fields
    Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = 
    fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();

    if(fielddataType != Schema.DisplayType.Reference) {
        leadList.add(new SelectOption(fieldLabel,fieldName));
    }
}
```